# Synchronize Bundler gem versions with yarn/npm package.json versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, yarnpkg, webpacker

I use Webpacker in a Ruby on Rails application with the repository hosted on GitHub. I've enabled GitHub's Dependabot service to receive notifications when dependencies can be updated (both in Gemfile and in package.json).

The problem is that Webpacker has both the Gemfile entry and the package.json entry and the versions should be synchronized (major versions of the gem and the js package should be the same).

Is there a tool which can check this for me? Or should I implement this myself? I guess it should not be very complex given there are parsers for both Gemfile and package.json/yarn.lock.